# cannot get spaces between string using join

Tags: python

I am using a deque and at the end I want to pop the items and add them to a string. So, I tried something like:

```
s = str()        
for _ in range(n):
    s += " ".join(str(q.pop()))
```

However, this does not put spaces between the values as I expected. To replicate:

```
from collections import deque
q = deque()
q.appendleft(1)
q.appendleft(2)
q.appendleft(3)

s = str()
for _in range(3):
    s += " ".join(str(q.pop()))

print(s)
```

This prints `'123'` instead of `'1 2 3'` as I was expecting. What am I doing wrong?

I am using python 3.5

Comment: `" ".join(str(1))` is just `'1'`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`" ".join()` joins the entries in an iterable together, but `q.pop()` only produces one item at a time.

Because `str(q.pop)` is still an iterable - since it's a string - `join()` doesn't complain at it, and just outputs each number.

If you'd had e.g. 17 in the queue, then when it was popped you'd get:

```
>>> " ".join(str(q.pop()))
'1 7'
```

Which would make it more obvious what was going wrong!

So what I'd suggest instead is:

```
from collections import deque
q = deque()
q.appendleft(1)
q.appendleft(2)
q.appendleft(3)

s = " ".join([str(q.pop()) for _ in range(3)])

print(s)
```

Where you make a list of strings based on the entries in the deque, using a list comprehension, and then join that with `" ".join()`.

Answer (score 1):

```
from collections import deque
q = deque()
q.appendleft(1)
q.appendleft(2)
q.appendleft(3)

s = str()
for _ in range(3):
    s = s + str(q.pop()) + ' '

print(s)
```

Comment: This will work, of course but I am curious as to why the first case does not work...

Comment: See my comment - because of the conversion to strings, it's taking each result as an iterable and then trying to join the characters in that together. It'd be more obvious what was going wrong with numbers that had two or more digits.

Comment: Also, this one will add an extra space at the end of your string at the end. You could instead make a list in that for-loop, and then use `join()` afterwards.